# Why is gcc saying I have the variable 'newNode' undeclared?

Tags: c, gcc, linked-list, undeclared-identifier

When I compile the following C code, gcc gives me an error complaining that 'newNode' is undeclared in the line `return newNode` however I don't understand why. Can anyone explain this error or how to fix it?

```
node *insertNode(node *first, int cases) {
int i;
int m;
int n;

for(i=1;i<=cases-1;i++) {
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    node *newNode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newNode->lower = m;
    newNode->upper = n;
    newNode->next = first;
    newNode = first;
}

return newNode; }
```

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: why are you using a haskell compiler? :p

Comment: don't cast the return of malloc, `node *newNode = malloc(sizeof *newNode);`

Comment: haha sorry, I was using C and Haskell last night, must have got confused between my gcc and ghci :P

Answer (score 3):

`newNode` is declared in a loop.  A variable declared in a block is out of scope outside the block.  Instead, you might want to declare an array of pointers to Nodes on the heap before the beginning of the loop, initialize them in the loop, and return the array.  If you do so, you will have to change the return type of your function to `node**`.

Answer (score 0):

The `newNode` variable is declared inside the `for` block (the part enclosed by curly braces). Therefore it is only valid/declared for that block, and not visible outside of it. The variable doesn't exist at the point of `return`.

You would need to create a `node** newNodeList` for the array of `node*`s, `malloc` memory for it, in the `for` loop save the single `node*`s in that space, and in the end return the created `newNodeList`.